# Taylor series converges

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

Let $h(x)=2^x$. Show that the Taylor series of $h(x)$ converges to $h(x)$ for all $x$.

I found the Taylor series to $$1+\ln(2)x+\frac{\ln^2(2)}{2}x^2+\frac{\ln^3(2)}{3!}x^3+\frac{\ln^4(2)}{4!}x^4+\ldots$$
Now, to show that it converges to $h(x)$ for all real $x$ is not obvious to me. Would it be the same as showing that the radius of convergence is $\infty$ and in that case how?

Comment: Can you use the fact that the Taylor series of the exponential function converges to the exponential function at every point of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes

Comment: No, it is not enough to show that the radius of convergence is infinite. There are functions for which the series has infinite radius of convergence and the series doesn't converge to the function. What you should do is to prove that the remainder tends to zero. You can use the [Lagrange form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder), for example.

Comment: @plop What is an example for such a power series you mention as a counterexample?

Comment: [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) the classic example. The Taylor series at $x=0$ is just $0+0x+0x^2+...$, which has infinite radius of convergence, but it converges to $0$, not to the function.

Comment: @plop Ok, I knew about that. However, in the case that the function you started with is holomorphic at the origin, you cannot have this issue, and that is the case with $2^x$. Thus, the OP's proposal is correct.

Comment: That is circular. If you already know that your function is analytic, then you already know that the series converges to the function, but that is what you want to prove in this case.

Comment: Just like the "argument" in the answer below, it doesn't have any substance. The same work you need to do to prove that $2^x$ is analytic is the one that you would need to do to prove that $e^x$ is analytic. So, passing the ball from $2^x$ to $e^x$ is not really telling you anything.

Comment: @plop I answered that I know that $exp(x)$ is analytic (i.e known that it is). Otherwise I would agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $x\in\Bbb R$,\begin{align}2^x&=\exp(\log(2)x)\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\log(2)x)^k}{k!}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\log^k(2)}{k!}x^k.\end{align}

Comment: So the argument is that the taylor series of $h(x)$ converges to $h(x)$ for all real $x$ because we can write $2^x$ as a series in terms of exp? I am not sure I am seeing the argument.

Comment: My argument consist in the fact that $2^x=\exp(\log(2)x)$ and in two other equalities. Which one of them do you think that it requires some justification?

Comment: @user879295 The power series of $e^w$ converges for all real $w$, in particular it converges for $w=x\log 2$ (with any real $x$) and it converges to $e^{x\log 2}=2^x$.

Comment: @Gary That is what I wanted. Thanks!